# Dealing with stylesheet order and css module className overrides

Tags: reactjs, css-modules

I have a component that has its own style, e.g.

```
.prompt { color: red; }
```

It's declared as so:

```
import cn from 'classnames';
import styles from './styles.css';

const MyComponent = ({className}) => {
  return (
    <div className={cn(styles.prompt, className)}>
      test
    </div>
  );
}
```

In my specific use case, the stylesheet for the className being passed in is actually defined and added to the head BEFORE the stylesheet from the module, so the module's css always overrides the style of the className being passed in. Something like:

[image]

Notice the `background: yellow` from second class is being overridden by the background from the module's own class.

Other than using !important in the secondary class, how can I work around this?

Comment: can we see cn code?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Comment: how styles are defined? I think you need to order the style rules.

Comment: There are lots of ways to increase the specificity of a selector without resorting to `!important`. Give the div an id, add some element names from the DOM tree to the selector (like `body div div.app__updatePrompt___32EkS`), etc.

Comment: Can you mark this as answered? @Chris?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on Mr. Lister's response, I re-evaluated my existing knowledge of specificity and came up with the following solution in the higher level css:

```
// in app.scss
.offline.prompt {
    color: red;
}

// in app.tsx
const classes = cn(Styles.offline, Styles.prompt);
return <OfflineApp className={classes}>...</OfflineApp>;
```

Essentially, I just tag the module markup with another sibling class to increase specificity and target the necessary properties using that. WAY better than abusing !important.

Comment: u can actually save some lines by doing `.offline.offline { ... }` and keep the `className` a bit cleaner